# Require header across routes without giving up 404

Tags: scala, akka-http

I’d like to require a header in my akka-http routes and can do so via

```
val route = headerValueByName("foo") { foo =>
  pathPrefix("path") {
    get {
      ...
    } ~ ...
  }
}
```

However, now any requests that don't match a path will get rejected with `400` (missing header) and not `404`.
Is there a neat way to get around this without repeatedly moving `headerValueByName` after the path matchers?

That is, is there a way to only apply an outer directive ( `headerValueByName`) and its rejections if the inner path and method matchers are successful?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you want to do in case the header is not specified, so I'll asume you want to return 400 (Bad request).

A possible solution is to use the optionalHeaderValueByName directive and then complete the request with the specified error, for example:

```
val route = optionalHeaderValueByName("foo") { optionalHeader =>
  optionalHeader map { header => 
    // rest of your routes
  } getOrElse complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest)
}
```